# Chilkat Support for Microsoft Visual Studio Xamarin IOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, chilkat

Is it possible to use the chilkat librarys for a Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Xamarin IOS or Android project?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to use the chilkat librarys for a Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Xamarin IOS or Android project?

Of course you can . You can add the project from NuGet.

> In VS for Mac

Right click the folder `Package` in your project->add Packages->search `chilkat`->Add Package
[image]

> in VS for Window

Right click your project ->Manage your project ->search `chilkat`->install

[image]

Now you can use the chilkat librays.

Comment: Thank you! And what about an IOS Xamarin Project for iPad? The windows librarys are not useable - is there a alternative (for e. g. cocoa pods) repository for native ios libs?

Comment: It is for iOS project both iPone and iPad

Comment: It doesn't work for android, the error says: Package chilkat-x64 9.5.0.80 is not compatible with monoandroid81

Answer (score 0):

Workaround use Chilkat in Xamarin 
https://medium.com/@hoangquach_65238/how-to-use-chilkat-library-in-xamarin-forms-ios-android-c34bd1f415ad

Comment: I've tried to implement this, and it works partially, but on some methods my app just crashes, like loading a public key certificate from a file (calling LoadFromFile method on PublicKey object). Have you managed to implement this?